# Is Spark's MapType deterministic, i.e. are key-val pairs correctly paired when manually exploding using map_keys/map_values?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

Is the order of a map in Spark deterministic?

In other words, if I were to call:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[{"a": 1, "b": 2}]],
    ["dictionary_col"]
)

df.select(
    F.map_keys("dictionary_col"),
    F.map_values("dictionary_col"),
)
```

Am I guaranteed to have something like

```
_key___|___value_
[a,b]  | [1,2]
```

or

```
_key___|___value_
[b,a]  | [2,1]
```

Or is there a chance that the dictionary will be "scrambled" in between the map_keys and the map_values call, leading to a mismatch in key/value?

```
_key___|___value_
[a,b]  | [2,1]
```

As an example, this could be a potential problematic run:
A example potential problematic run:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 } --> getKeys --> [a, b]
<shuffle> <---node crashes, reloads data --> { b:2, a:1 }
{ b:2, a:1 } --> getVals --> [2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map_keys` and `map_values` methods make no guarantee on the order of keys and values they return.  These two methods are [documented](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_keys) only to "[r]etur[n] an *unordered* array containing the keys [or values, respectively] of the map" (emphasis added).  Thus, there is not even a guarantee that the order of keys and values will correspond to the order of their key-value pairs in the map, even though it may appear that way in the current version of Spark.